# React JSX: Include expression {props.expr} inside another object expression {props.outerexpr.{props.expr}}

Tags: reactjs

I have a subcomponent which receives `{props.name}`. I need to include that expression in an outer object expression, `{props.values.{..}}`. But the following JSX gives an error:

```
        <Form.Control as="select" 
                    custom 
                    id={'timeDropdown-' + props.name}
                    name={props.name}
                    value={props.values.{props.name}} {/* ERROR HERE */}
                    onChange={props.handleChange}
                    onBlur={props.handleBlur}                                                     
        >
```

The idea is that e.g. `value=props.values.week1` will be set when using

```
<MyComp name='week1'>
```

Comment: value={props.values[props.name]}

Comment: that is a syntax error try @Georgy solution